# Using Google Sheet as a web service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a complex sheet with many formulas and cell values which calculates result based on some given values in particular cells. 
Basically, I want to use this sheet as a function: web service based calculator, which takes arguments (from other web app) and spits out some json result.
Now the last part (returning data) is handled by Google Script `doGet` function, like `ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(output))`.

What I wonder is: how should I feed the sheet my input arguments?

I want this "calculator" to be used by several users (possibly) at once, so I guess I can't update cells in the sheet to get calculated values otherwise I'll get some issues like write conflicts etc?

Is there something like virtual cells in Google Sheet? Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: You can use LockService to prevent conflicts, but it's more of a hit/miss when concurrent requests are too fast. There's also a ceiling of 30 concurrent requests.

Comment: @TheMaster, is there a way/hack to not have a concurrent writing to a shared resource (sheet cell)? May be make a copy of a whole sheet and then delete it or something like that?

Comment: You're probably better off reproducing your logic in JavaScript, as then it doesn't have shared resources to use. Alternately, duplicate your calculation sheet a bunch (taking care that it doesn't have too many cells or too much data that you violate the internal size limits), and track which ones are being used with `CacheService`

Comment: @tehhowch, that's the main thing - the sheet with formulas and calculations is supposed to be a black box, which only analyst understands and edits, so I can't/shouldn't reproduce the logic in Javascript. I will check `CacheService` though, thanks!

Comment: Tell the analyst to write it in JavaScript ;)

Comment: @Twice `LockService` is the way. When I say too fast, I mean really really fast - in order of milliseconds.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, can't accept your comment though. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: One of the problems with this sort of question is that you get many different opinions.  Personally, I would use your complex spreadsheet as a template that gets copied for each user.

Comment: @Cooper, getting many different opinions is exactly why I posted this question :) could you elaborate on your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining formulas with script is not recommended, because it's inefficient and error prone. However, If there's no other alternative, the following can be attempted.

- `LockService` is used to prevent conflicts
- `flush()`  is used to prevent caching

#### Snippet:

```
/**
* Retrieves value in a spreadsheet based on inputs provided
* @param {Number} a1 - A number to input in a1 of sheet1
* @param {Number} b1 - A number to input in b1 of sheet1
* @return {Number} c1 - The value in c1, which was modified by formulas? due to a1 and b1 inputs
*/
function blackBox_(a1,b1) {
  try{
    LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(2000);//Wait to get lock for 2s(Unreliable?)
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ss.getRange("Sheet1!A1:B1").setValues([[a1,b1]]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //flush the changes
    return ss.getRange("Sheet1!C1").getValue();
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
}

function doGet(e){
  //e=e || {};
  const par = e.parameter || {};
  const a1 = par.a1 || 2;
  const b1 = par.b1 || 2;
  console.log(blackBox_(a1,b1))
}
```

#### References:

- [doGet(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)
- [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)